# The highlight color used for updated favorite questions is too light to see

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, design

At least on my screen (Dell laptop, Windows 7, default color settings), I have a very difficult time seeing which question(s) are highlighted on the profile favorites tab. If I guess wrong (and click a not-highlighted question, expecting to see some activity) and then go back, it doesn't help that the questions are no longer highlighted on the subsequent page load. Can you please make the highlight color more distinct from the background color?

Also, the `.tagged-interesting` color for highlighted questions (#ffefc6) displays fine. Any reason the favorite highlight color is different?

[image: favorites]

Comment: This may be due to the color profile used in your display settings/OS. Including the info would be helpful.

Comment: I can see this clearly until I'm about 20-30 degrees above the laptop screen perpendicular. At 45 degrees, the vote score box background in the related panes blends into the background and inverts to lighter than the white around. The yellow inverts at about 50-60 degrees above the perpendicular plane.

Comment: @nickhar Using default settings for Windows 7 on both my laptop and my work desktop. I can't see it well on either unless I lower my head so it's perpendicular with the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen your comment and updated answer and in contrast to my initial comment, the colour used to highlight favourites (#FEFEDD) is not the same colour used to highlight regular questions (#FFEFC6) in other areas of the site: [interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting), [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), [hot](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) etc.

This colour seems to be used exclusively for updates to tabs in the user profile (which I've just seen on my own profile) but which disappear after viewing them once.

**User profile tabs example (from favourites tab):**

[image]

**Other areas of the site:**

[image]

If it's causing perpendicular viewing angles, then I'd be tempted to suggest colour alignment/standardisation in terms of highlighting on the site unless this is by-design* to purposefully differentiate between **favorite tags** and **updates**.

Different monitors/displays can cause enormous colour variations which are usually more visible on laptop screens (*especially at the cheaper end of the market, where laptops basically have a built-in privacy screen due to the quality of the display*). The lighter they are the more perpendicular you'll need to be!

*You could write scriptlet or similar to dynamically change the highlighting colours based on the CSS classes if it's by design...